# Time complexity of insertion and removing in 2-3 trees

Tags: time-complexity, b-tree, 2-3-tree

Why do insertion and removing operations in 2-3 tree always have complexity of O(logn), is there a mathematical proof?

Comment: I know it's O(logn) and understand why. But I don't understand why removing and insertion operations have the same complexity

Comment: But what about split operation when inserting a value to a node? It can be performed all the way up to the root.

Comment: I didn't get it :(

Comment: You write about subtree below the place I have to insert. But I can insert only in leaves. What subtree are writing about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When we insert a key at level , in the worst case we need to split
   `+ 1` nodes (one at each of the  levels plus the root).
- A `2-3 tree` containing  keys with the maximum number of levels takes
  the form of a binary tree where each internal node has one key and
  two children.
- In such a tree  `= (2^(+1)) − 1` where  is the number of the lowest
  level.
- This implies that  `+ 1 = log( + 1)` from which we see that the splits are in the worst case  `log`  .
- So insertion in a `2-3 tree` takes at worst    time.
- Similarly we can prove that searches and deletions take   
  time.